# Code Composer - Eclipse IDE menu color settings

Tags: eclipse, themes, code-composer

I'm using Code Composer Studio 12 with the custom theme "spectrum".
Even if I love this color scheme, I struggle to find a possible solution on how to change the IDE menu colors and the selected item color in the preferences menu.

Does anyone knows how to change those manually?

[UPDATE]

I'm on windows 11

[image][image]

Comment: Is this on Windows 10? If yes, then probably the Code Composer Studio version you have are based on a pretty old Eclipse (otherwise the menu should also be dark).

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention it, it's windows 11. The CCS is the latest version, I don't think I have a way to change the Elclipse version underneath

Comment: Yes, this is something you cannot do on your end. But you might ask the Code Composer Studio development team for an update.